# C# List<T> Sort with IComparer argument gives compilation error

Tags: c#, list, sorting, icomparer

Can someone explain to me how this is supposed to work? I followed an MSDN example I found at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/234b841s.aspx .

I have made my own CustomObject and have made a Comparer for it.

Here is the `CustomObjectComparer` class:

```
public class CustomObjectComparer : System.Collections.Generic.IComparer<CustomObject>
{
    public int Compare(CustomObject co1, CustomObject co2)
    {
         //Impementation Omitted
    }

}
```

Then when I have a `List<CustomObject>` and try to do the following I get compile errors.

```
List<CustomObject> list = new List<CustomObject>();
CustomObjectComparer comparer = new CustomObjectComparer();
list.Sort(comparer);
```

Errors: 
`Argument 1: cannot convert from 'CustomObjectComparer' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IComparer<CustomObject>'`

Isn't `CustomObjectComparer` a `System.Collections.Generic.IComparer`?

Comment: Are you sure that's the exact error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<strike>It looks your list contains `CustomObjectComparer`s, not `CustomObject`s.</strike>

You can either pass a comparer that can compare `CustomObjectComparer`s, or (more likely) change the list to a `List<CustomObject>`.

**EDIT**: This would happend if you have two types named `CustomObject`, or if you also have a different error.

Comment: I agree with SLaks.  Show us the code where you initialize the "list" variable.  I believe that may be your problem

Comment: Thanks guys, I copied over the error wrong. I have editted to be correct and also have added the initialization of the "list" variable.

Comment: Hey SLaks, that comment helped me. I am trying to create a SortableBindingList for CustomObject and had declared it like `code` public class CustomObjectSortableBindingList<CustomObject> : BindingList<CustomObject>`code` When I removed that and tried, it compiled just fine. Looks like a I need a different approach. Thanks for your help.